# "Cannot read property 'content' of null": Psuedo Elements

Tags: javascript, css, cordova

I adapted some code from [here](http://www.fettblog.eu/blog/2012/04/16/robust-but-hacky-way-of-portraitlandscape-detection/) in order to detect orientation changes in my Phonegap app (to load different CSS files for landscape and portrait). I'm getting a "cannot read property 'content' of null error, implying there's something wrong with the DOM call. The code involves adding these psuedo elements to the primary CSS file:

```
/*Orientation Detection Hack*/
body:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    color: transparent;
}

@media all and (orientation: portrait) {
    body:after {
        content: "p";
    }
}

@media all and (orientation: landscape) {
    body:after {
        content: "l";
    }
}
/*end of orientation detection*/
```

And this event listener to check the pseudo element on an orientation change:

```
/*ORIENTATION CHANGES*/
    //get style of the body:after element
var bodyAfterStyle = window.getComputedStyle(document.body, ":after");

window.onorientationchange = function() {


  navigator.notification.alert(
        'ORIENTATION CHANGELOL',  // message
        'Credits',            // title
        'Credits');              // buttonName

  if(bodyAfterStyle.content == 'p') {

/*whatever
    navigator.notification.alert("Now in Portrait");
    var sheet = document.createElement('link');
    sheet.innerHTML = 'href=\"portrait.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\"  type=\"text/css\"';
    document.body.appendChild(sheet);
end whatever*/
} 
    else if(bodyAfterStyle.content == 'l') {
    //do landscape stuff
  }
}
    /*END OF ORIENTATION STUFF*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that bodyAfterStyle is lost, i would propose to move its assignment into the event function.

Comment: This seems to have done it... although nothing inside the if statement is being executed, even when I comment out everything but an alert!

Answer (score 0):

You need to request the computed style in the `orientationchange` event handler to get the **new pseudo-element**'s styles.

Quoting the [Document Object Model CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-CSSview-getComputedStyle) W3C Spec on `getComputedStyle`:

> Since a computed style is related to an Element node, if this element is removed from the document, the associated CSSStyleDeclaration and CSSValue related to this declaration are no longer valid.

The explanation for your case is that the pseudo-element instance changes when the media query kicks in. The pseudo-element is actually removed and replaced with a new one. In your code the `bodyAfterStyle` reference points to the old instance which is no longer available.

Comment: But the getComputedStyle comes after the orientation change? I don't really understand why it doesn't refer to the new one. Does getComputedStyle perform a new media query?

Comment: I just tried your code on an iPad and it does work as you expect it, no errors. However, there's an easier way to get device orientation by using the window.matchMedia() API. Here's an example: http://jsbin.com/itadad/1/edit

Comment: There's even a polyfill for matchMedia if you need to support older devices: https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/