# mediaMatch in Android? (Phonegap orientation)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm struggling with orientation changed in Phonegap. My plan was to change CSS file when the orientation changed (maybe thats a convoluted way of doing it anyway), but I'm struggling to get any orietation dependant events to happen. I'm currently using the code:

```
window.onorientationchange = function() {

  navigator.notification.alert(
        'orientation change!',  // message
        'Portrait',            // title
        'buttton');              // buttonName

  if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches){
      navigator.notification.alert(
        'now in portrait',  // message
        'Portrait',            // title
        'buttton');              // buttonName
  }
  else{
    alert("landscape")
  }
}
```

The first alert (whenever orientation changes) is fine, but the second (when it specifically changes into landscape) isn't happening. I'm on Android version 2.3.5. (this method was suggested by Razvan on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583062/cannot-read-property-content-of-null-psuedo-elements/14603167#comment20464120_14603167) question)

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a listener on the MediaQueryList object. See below for example.

There are ways other than media queries to retrieve device orientation change. Search "mdn orientationchange" for examples.

1. Create MediaQueryList object, 'orientation'. Contains add/removeListener, media and matches.
2. Create listener, 'orientationListener'. Tests for media query match.
3. Get the initial orientation value
4. Listen for any change to occur

   ```
   var orientation = window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)"),
       orientationListener = function(mql) {

           if (mql.matches) {
               // Media query does match orientation portrait
           } else {
               // Media query does not match which should mean orientation is now landscape
           }

       };

   // Gets initial match

   orientationListener(orientation);

   // Listens for change

   orientation.addListener(orientationListener);
   ```